# Django filter dynamic field name based on queryset

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a queryset with several annotations, including two fields: `price` and `price_after_discount`. I want to implement a max_filter based on a specific value. However, I need to handle a condition: if the `price_after_discount` field is not equal to 0, the filter should be applied on that field; otherwise, the filter should be applied on the `price` field.

I've attempted the following code, although it's not functioning correctly. This is a sample code:

```
value = 200
queryset.filter(
    Case(
        When(price_after_discount=0, then=F("price")),
        default=F("price_after_discount")
    )__lt=value
)
```

Can you please provide guidance on how to properly implement this max_filter condition based on the `price_after_discount` and `price` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias) for the expression, and then [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias) on that alias:

```
queryset.alias(
    my_price=Case(
        When(price_after_static_discount=0, then=F('price')),
        default=F('price_after_discount'),
    )
).filter(my_price__lt=value)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work but it kind of looks like annotating, and i wanted to avoid that since i already done a lot of complex annotations, so price_after_discount is annotated field that has a really complex query. can you explain how is the performance of alias?

Comment: @scaryhamid: the difference is that for alias, you not add it to the `SELECT` clause, it simply replaces `my_price` in the filter with the expression.